# pentadiagonal matrix vector multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, computational-complexity, numerical-linear-algebra, numerical-optimization

I have a pentadiagonal symmetric matrix , with elements on the diagonal, on the 1st upper-diagonal and 1st lower-diagonal and at the n-th upper and lower diagonal.
( n changes values from one matrix to an other but the form of the matrices is always pentadiagonal )

For example for a 6x6 matrix, if n=4 I have this matrix. ( Notice that A[4,3]=A[3,4]=0 not -0.09)
\begin{pmatrix}
\ 32.18 & -0.09 & 0 & -16 & 0 &0
\\ -0.09 & 32.18 &  -0.09 &  0 &  -16& 0  
\\ 0 & -0.09 & 32.18 & 0 & 0 & -16
\\ -16   &  0 &    0  &  32.18 & -0.09  & 0
\\0  & -16   &  0  &  -0.09 & 32.18 & -0.09
\\ 0 & 0 & -16 & 0 & -0.09 & 32.18
\end{pmatrix}

Is there any way to calculate the A*x product where x is a (6x1) vector, ignoring the multiplications by zeros no matter what the value of n is?

Comment: This is more of a data-structural problem than a mathematical problem. For a general matrix $A$ with a small number of nonzero entries if $A$ is stored using a [compressed sparse row or column format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix), the product $Ax$ can be computed from a single pass over the nonzero entries of $A$ using a simple for-loop. Your matrix has a particular tensor product structure, which @Omnomnomnom shows can be used to develop an extra clean formula for the matrix-vector product.

Answer (score 0):

In your particular case, you can partition the matrix into
$$
M = \left[\begin{array}{ccc|ccc}
\ 32.18 & -0.09 & 0 & -16 & 0 &0
\\ -0.09 & 32.18 &  -0.09 &  0 &  -16& 0  
\\ 0 & -0.09 & 32.18 & 0 & 0 & -16\\ 
\hline
-16   &  0 &    0  &  32.18 & -0.09  & 0
\\0  & -16   &  0  &  -0.09 & 32.18 & -0.09
\\ 0 & 0 & -16 & 0 & -0.09 & 32.18
\end{array}\right] = \pmatrix{A & -16 I\\
-16I & A}.
$$
If you partition the column-vector $x$ into $x = (x_1,x_2)$, each vector size $3$, then we have
$$
Mx = \pmatrix{A & -16I\\-16I & A} \pmatrix{x_1\\x_2} = \pmatrix{Ax_1 - 16x_2\\-16x_1 + Ax_2}.
$$
Also, with the [vectorization operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)) $\operatorname{vec}:\Bbb R^{3 \times 2} \to \Bbb R^6$, we have
$$
Mx = \operatorname{vec}(A\operatorname{vec}^{-1}(x) + \operatorname{vec}^{-1}(x)B),
$$
where $B = \pmatrix{0&-16\\-16 & 0}$. Perhaps these ideas generalize.